# Adapt dynamic treeview bootstrap to my BDD in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, treeview

I have a problem with php array. I finally want to have a array like this. Here is what I need :

```
$arr = [
    [
        'text' => '2018-11-01>123456>cassa',
        'nodes' => [
            [
                'text' => '32weds>has>aaaaa',
                'nodes' => [
                    [
                        'text' => '32.png',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'text' => 'aegergert24562>han>asdfsd',
                'nodes' => [
                    [
                        'text' => '32(1).png',
                    ],
                ],
            ],

        ],
    ],
    [
        'text' => '2018-11-02>1234>cassa',
        'nodes' => [
            [
                'text' => 'qwerty>has>aaaaa',
                'nodes' => [
                    [
                        'text' => 'rr.png',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'text' => 'sDFSDF>ha>aaaaa',
                'nodes' => [
                    [
                        'text' => 'ff.png',
                    ],

                ],
            ],

        ],

    ],
];

$data = $arr;
echo json_encode($data);
```

So my php code with several tests is as follows:

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM saisie order by date, n_trans, destination, n_fact, client, transitaire ";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sub_data["code"] = $row["code"];
    $sub_data["text"] = $row["date"] . '>' . $row["n_trans"] . '>' . $row["destination"];
    $sub_data["text1"] = $row["n_fact"] . '>' . $row["client"] . '>' . $row["transitaire"];
    $sub_data["nom_doc"] = $row["nom_doc"];
    $data[] = $sub_data;
}
$output = array();
foreach ($data as &$value) {
    $id = $value['text'];
    $id1 = $value['text1'];
    if (!isset($id)) {
        if (!array_key_exists($value['text1'], $output)) {
            $output[$id1] = array(
                'text' => $id1,
                'nodes' => array()
            );
        }
        $output[$id1]['text'] = &$value;
    } else {
        if (!array_key_exists($value['text'], $output)) {
            $output[$id] = array(
                'text' => $id,
                'nodes' => array()
            );
        }
        $output[$id]['nodes'][$id1] = &$value;
    }
}
```

and as I am not really strong in array, I can not achieve the same result.

Comment: How do you know that `qwerty>has>aaaaa` and `sDFSDF>ha>aaaaa` are child nodes of `2018-11-02>1234>cassa`?
Additionally `if (!isset($id))` will always be TRUE, since you set the variable two lines before that condition. You can get rid of that condition altogether, if you unify the input data; e.g.: `if(!empty($row["date"])) { $sub_data["text"] = … } else { $sub_data["text"] = … }`.
Overall you problem does not look like a poor understanding of arrays.

Comment: qwerty>has>aaaaa and sDFSDF>ha>aaaaa has the same date, n_trans and destination .

Comment: $query = " SELECT * FROM saisie order by date, n_trans, destination, n_fact, client, transitaire "; and  'qwerty>has>aaaaa' is  'date >n_trans>destination'.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.